# Print two strings which has newlines in it next to each other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to create a console based digital clock, lets say its 12pm, I need my code to output the one:

```
    ██
    ██
    ██
    ██
    ██
```

and the two:

```
██████
    ██        
██████
██
██████
```

next to each other, what happens is this:

```
    ██
    ██
    ██
    ██
    ██
██████
    ██        
██████
██
██████
```

I hope someone can help me!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You're going to need to break up each digit into lines, and print each line of each digit at the same time, instead of the whole `1`, then the whole `2`. You could also use a console manipulation library like ncurses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `splitlines`, then `zip` the resulting lists together and print the pairs:

```
>>> for pair in zip(*map(str.splitlines, (one, two))): 
>>>     print(*pair) 
...
    ██ ██████
    ██     ██
    ██ ██████
    ██ ██
    ██ ██████
```

If you want to update those values as time goes by, this will not really work, though, using `print`, since you can not go back to overwrite previous lines. Instead, you might want to have a look at [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html). Very simple example, just cycling through the two digits:

```
import curses, time, itertools
times = itertools.cycle([(one, two), (two, one)])

s = curses.initscr()
while True:
    s.clear()
    for i, d in enumerate(next(times)):
        for k, l in enumerate(d.splitlines()):
            s.addstr(k, i*7, l)
    s.refresh()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split each in different lines, then use to `zip` to iterate both at the same time

```
one = """    ██
    ██
    ██
    ██
    ██"""

two = """██████
    ██        
██████
██
██████"""


for value in zip(one.splitlines(), two.splitlines()):
    print(*value)
```